# Migrating Logic App to new subscription, changing API

Tags: connection, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

I have cloned an existing logic app in subscription Azure-Sub1 that uses Managed Identity for 2 api connections. I can move the logic app to new subscription Azure-Prod. The old connections are still referencing the resources in Azure-Sub1. I have tried to change the connection in the logic app, but I can't save it as it still references the old connection. How can change them to reference the new subscription resources or delete the old ones?

I tried editing the logic app changing the api connections but i will not let me save them.

I tried to download the logic in Visual Studio 2019, but I can't make changes since the api connections are using Managed Identities.

Any suggestions or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to Move logic app from one subscription to other subscription. One of the ways is using move option in resource properties page.
[image]
Another option is exporting logic app template and deploying it to required subscription.

1. I have created a logic app as shown below in one subscription,

[image]

2. To retrieve secret from key vault using system managed identity.
3. Exporting template of logic app as shown below,
   [image]
4. Template file with parameters will be downloaded into local system.
5. Next search for Deploy custom template resource in Azure portal.
   [image]
6. Click on build your own template in the editor.
7. Select Load file and upload the downloaded template,
   [image]
8. Once loaded click on save.
9. You can select target subscription and connections will be loaded automatically. If needed we can edit from here,
   [image]
10. Logic app created in target subscription as shown below,
    [image]
    logic app ran successfully
    [image]
    Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/move-logic-app-resources)

Comment: Thanks for the information.   When the logic app uses key vault in another subscription, the api connections are not valid in the new subscription.   I can change the connections in logic app but it doesn't remove the old connections.   The logic app won't save new version.

Comment: Create a logic app with api connection in a region.   Move logic app to new region and subscription.